# Customize Vtiger

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

I am working on vtiger customization.

I changed the UI but i want to know where the mysql query executes.

Is there any common function to execute all query?.

I got one function which call by all pages that is `$this->database->Execute($sql);`

can anyone tell me the exact function of query or how the flow works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Queries in vtiger may go through different pathes, but if you use mysql, the last place of all is:

> {path of Vtiger}\adodb\drivers\adodb-mysql.inc.php

```
    function _query($sql,$inputarr)
```

You can even log all queries

```
    function _query($sql,$inputarr)
{
    $hl = fopen("my_log.sql","a+");
    fwrite($hl, "--------"."\n".$sql."\n");
    fclose($hl);        
    return mysql_query($sql,$this->_connectionID);
}
```

my_log.sql will be created in vtiger root directory. Also vtiger has it's own log, but I prefer mine.
another points to mention:

> Mainly vtiger uses it built-in function named pquery. I suggest do not
>   go through this function to understand it. Most of the times the chain of a called pquery function has more than 3 members. But I think it worth to
>   find out how it does the queries. Simply you write the inputs an
>   pquery does the job!